# Will any skin/theme/persona of firefox slow my firefox?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, performance

Will any skin/theme/persona of Firefox slow my Firefox, compare to default theme, even little ? is it good to stick with Default Firefox look/theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, one basic theme shouldn't be more resource intensive than another basic theme. If it's just a change in color or non-animated images, then it takes the same amount of CPU/memory to draw one image as it does another.

If the theme you're talking about has excessive animations or other fancy features, these might come with a performance hit.

Comment: I'm thinking to use this theme https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3699/. Theme file size is 754 KB.

Comment: That theme looks perfectly fine, and should perform just as well as the default - There's mention of custom scrollbars, which *might* have a performance penalty, *might* not. More likely *not*. Just try it and see is all I can really recommend.

Answer (score 0):

First, it depends, if you've one more candy in your pocket, your body is absolutely heavier. Computer nowadays is fast, and there's no problem to use customized theme in firefox. You'll stick or not, it depends on u, you should pick one suit you or maybe default is the best :)
Best regard,